# Can I get the Ubuntu 17.10 beta

Tags: 17.04, 17.10

Can I opt in to get the Ubuntu 17.10 daily builds from within I Ubuntu 17.04 or will I have to install the daily build/ beta from a USB bootable device?

Comment: 17.04 still has bugs. wait for LTS( 18 may be)

Comment: @AbdullaNilam I'm running Kubuntu 17.10 Daily, and it's very solid.